# SELECT row_security_active('certain_table') returns False no matter what

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I am trying to set up row level security in an Amazon RDS database (Postgres 15) to power a Django project.

The user I pass to Django is not superuser and doesn't have `BYPASSRLS` inherited from any of it's roles. I know that from this query:

```
SELECT
    rolname,
    rolsuper,
    rolbypassrls
FROM
    pg_roles
WHERE
    oid in (
        WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
            SELECT
                oid
            FROM
                pg_roles
            WHERE
                rolname = current_user
            UNION
            ALL
            SELECT
                m.roleid
            FROM
                cte
                JOIN pg_auth_members m ON m.member = cte.oid
        )
        SELECT
            oid
        FROM
            cte
    )
```

The user does own the database, schema and table, but when I added the policy I also ran:

```
ALTER TABLE certain_table ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
ALTER TABLE certain_table FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

On a local Postgres (Docker) and the same setup, executing `SELECT row_security_active('certain_table')` return `True`. On RDS it returns `False`.

Am I missing any other criteria for bypassing row level security?

Comment: Is there anything `rds_superuser` has that makes them bypass RLS while having `rolsuper=False` and `rolbypassrls=False`?

Comment: What is the value of the parameter `row_security`? Also, consider the possibility that AMAZON hacked up this part of the code.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It's on. Apparently `rds_superuser` has something that makes them bypass RLS. We changed the user and it works now. Would be good to know what's provoking the bypass, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As provisional answer, there's something in `rds_superuser` that makes them bypass RLS. What exactly, that is still unknown to me. I changed the user and RLS is working properly now. A better answer would be to know exactly how the bypass is happening, so that it can be detected from a query to the server.